# How to create object masker (div covers all surface current control) by using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need some function in jQuery like the following code. The **createmask** function must create div that covers all surface of current object. Moreover, this function need to support a lot of position style of current control like static, absolute, fixed and so on.

```
$('sometextbox').createmask()
```

For more information, Please look at the below picture.

[Masking process http://qmv6sa.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pfKPdILX8hz97SXGIzpk70HdKUibvkz0V5wZ37mSibekfL_Qnk3FZ-IS07gqOXq24zVF1A1C-IvPR6sOmxbHJPd8jHK6xIj_c/MaskObject.PNG](http://cid-f093f24662880947.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/StackOverFlow/MaskObject.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

Eeep, this is one of those questions where I think more information needs to be determined before a proper answer can be given.
First off, why are you trying to do this? If the idea is to make an input field 'disabled' then creating a masker like this is never going to work.
You also have to think what will happen for screenreaders dealing with this.

Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve, you may have better luck simply styling the input field itself rather than trying to overlay some extra content on top of it that is going to fail the first time someone who uses keyboard navigation tabs through your content.

So yeah, if you could try and explain what the intent behind this is, we might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I want to create some control about inline indicator like password-strength indicator or search process indicator. Moreover, it can apply this input to create menu or other controls that depend on object position.

Comment: I know the easiest way to create menu is creating absolute position-based object. However, this way does not work when I use it for fixed position-based object (this menu will not stay on the original place when I scroll window).

Comment: Moreover, I cannot use styling the input field for this question. For example, watermark password textbox. It is impossible to change input type (from password type => text type) at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might be what you're looking for: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/
You can also look at that code and just grab what you need.